# How to rotate a child game object everytime when parent rotates?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, rotation

I have a GameObject called Gun, and a GameObject called Hand which is a child of other GameObject named Player.

When I pick up the gun, it becomes a child of the hand.

The problem is, when the player rotates (and so, Hand rotates too), the gun's not rotating, it stays at the same rotation.

Here's the Gun script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LaserGun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Hand;
    public Transform LaserSpawnPoint;
    public Movement movement;
    public Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    public GameObject Laser;
    public bool IsInHand;

    public void Start()
    {
        Hand = GameObject.Find("Hand");

        movement = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Movement>();

        rb2D = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Hand").transform;
        this.transform.position = Hand.transform.position;
        GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
        IsInHand = true;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && IsInHand == true)
        {
            Instantiate(Laser, LaserSpawnPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && IsInHand == true)
        {
            this.transform.parent = null;
            GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
            IsInHand = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the Player's movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float moveInput;

    public GameObject Hand;
    public GameObject HeldObj;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    public bool facingRight = true;

    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        Hand.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
            Hand.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -180, 0));
        }
        else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
            Hand.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 180, 0));
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
}
```

Some info (might be useful)

- The game is 2D
- The "Hand" object is an empty game object
- There is no animator on player and the gun objects

I tried to upload the image of this but for some reason Stack does not let me do this.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you can create a property you will use to rotate parent objects via only. And inside this property you can have Action that will rotate the child object. Or create custom subscribtion for parent rotation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult to determine from just your code what is the issue, because a lot of things can be causing the issue.

1. Is your Gun parented to the Player when picked up? I know your code says it does, but you may want to check in your Inspector when playing to see if it actually is, because other Components or snippets of code may be unparenting it.
2. An Animator may be affecting the positioning and rotation of your Gun or Player, and this may in turn be affecting your Gun and making it not rotate properly.
3. Is the Player a skinned mesh? If it has a skeleton, and your "Hand" object is a mesh, it may move weirdly. For skinned meshes, you will want to parent objects to the bones instead of the meshes when you want them to move with the body part.

I'm sorry my answer isn't more specific, but Unity has a lot of different moving parts, and I need more information to be able to pinpoint the issue more specifically for you.

Comment: I will try to edit the question and add the screenshot to it so it might get more clear than it is now, I hope it will get better to understand